# 'loginForm object has no attribute 'is_valid' in django why i'm getting this

Tags: python, django

> 'loginForm' object has no attribute 'is_valid' can anyone have solution why i'm getting this
> i just trey to get data and the form it shows  error  on this  line `is_valid()` in django

```
>login.py 

        <form action ='' method ='POST'  > 
        {% csrf_token %}
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="formGroupExampleInput">User Name</label>
            <input type="text" id='username' name = 'username' class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="">
          </div>
        <label for="inputPassword5">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name ='password' id="password" class="form-control" aria-describedby="passwordHelpBlock">
        <input class="btn btn-primary my-3" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        
        
        </div>
    
    > views.py 
    
        def login(request):
            if not request.user.is_authenticated:
                if request.method == 'POST':
                    form = loginForm(request.POST)
                    if form.is_valid():
                        username = models.cleaned_data['username']
                        password = models.cleaned_data['password']
                        user = authenticate(username=username , password=password)
                        if user is not None:
                            login(request , user)
                            messages.success(request,'logged in Successfully !!')
                            return HttpResponseRedirect('dashbord')
            
                        
                else:
                    form = loginForm()
                    
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('dashbord')
            return render(request,'login.html',{'form':form})
        
        
     def logout(request):
     return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        
        
        
     > models.py  
     class loginForm(models.Model):
     username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     password = models.EmailField(max_length=200  )
```

Comment: Please don't spam the same question multiple times... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65517768/loginform-object-has-no-attribute-is-valid-in-django. `loginForm` is a `Model` and not a `Form`

Comment: after that also getting error

Answer (score 1):

Your `loginForm` is *not* a form. It is a *model*, and models do not have a `.is_valid()` method. Models are not used to process, validate and clean data, but to *store* data. It thus does not make much sense to use a model here.

You should define a form

```
# app_name/forms.py

from django import forms

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
```

In your view, you can then make use of that form:

```
# app_name/views.py

from app_name.forms import LoginForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def login(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = LoginForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                username = models.cleaned_data['username']
                password = models.cleaned_data['password']
                user = authenticate(username=username , password=password)
                if user is not None:
                    login(request , user)
                    messages.success(request,'logged in Successfully !!')
                    return redirect('dashbord')
                else:
                    form = LoginForm() 
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('dashbord')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request,'login.html',{'form':form})
```